# Trying to post image to Instagram from a Javascript using Instagram API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am doing this in Google App Scripts. Seems pretty straightforward, so I first setup Meta Developer info, and created a Instagram Test User and created a valid long-lived token for that account to use.

```
var userID = "139**********890";
// a fresh Instagram API Long Live Access Token
var accessToken = "IGQVJWRzBzWGp2d1hIUThZ*****************************************************************************************************************cWVFclczbDBmTEx0U1B2RAZDZD";

function insertPost3() {
    var formData = {
    'image_url': "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10QubQQV218reR2qSQ-9qA0QmrOoYoCIL&export=download",
    'caption': "here is sample text",
    'access_token': accessToken
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userID + '/media';

  Logger.log(container);

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': accessToken
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userID + '/media_publish';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
}
```

And just getting a generic error back, even with muteHttpExceptions. Not sure how to proceed.

```
Exception: Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AhuSzful3sLsd7qKziJH6Oi"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

Any ideas, sample code, or resources to read would be great.

This is one of the guides I've been using to do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Thanks for any help!!

phi

Comment: recheck userId and accessToken

Comment: Thank you! I have found many different docs online that show ways to find the userid to use, but none of them are working. I saw where this URL gives you back JSON response of all your user data, tried the ID that came in that as well, no luck.

https://www.instagram.com/phiofkhem/?__a=1

Any other ideas? I created the token in "Instagram Basic Display" -> User Token Generator and generated a long lived token. That should work, just not sure if I am using the correct userID?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Phi of Khem Thank you for replying. From `Does anyone know where to get the UserID?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. So I understood that my answer was not useful for your question. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No your answer was helpful for sure, no reason to delete my friend! I just want to confirm that the user ID I am using is the correct one to be using for the API call. In other words, how are people who are successfully makings getting their Instagram User ID to use? And I am using a user token I generated from the site, that should also work for this call correct? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

get instagram id(from GET account details).

get Long Live user access token.

get Long Live page access token.

use page access token to upload the image. Please note, this LLPAT needs access token together in the URL. it will return media id

use media id to create a insta post with caption